# how to prevent Poetry to consider .gitignore

Tags: python, packaging, python-packaging, python.net

I am working on a python project which uses pythonnet with several C# dll's as dependencies.
As I do not want to push the dll's to the git repository I adapted the .gitignore file. However, now Poetry does not include the dll's into the python package.

Is there a way to force Poetry to ignore the .gitignore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the `.gitignore` just serves as the default-settings for `poetry`s inclusion/exclusion list. You can configure it manually with the `include` field, which is documented [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude).

In your case, you just need to specify the dll folder that you are excluding in your gitignore:

**.gitignore**

```
# ...
src/dlls
```

**pyproject.toml**

```ini
[tool.poetry]
# ...
include = [
    "src/dlls/some.dll",  # listing files explicitly
    "src/dlls/*",         # all files in "src/dlls"
    "src/dlls/**/*",      # all files in "src/dlls" and any subfolders
    "src/dlls/**/*.dll",  # all files in "src/dlls" and any subfolders
                          # with the file ending ".dll"
]
```

Comment: Thank you @Arne. By the way: I obtained that an exclude does not work for the `__pycache__` folder. However this is not a big deal as I will handle it anyway with the .gitignore file.

Comment: happy to help. good to know about the `__pycache__`, I've been lucky enough with all my project that having just the .gitignore settings was enough.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Even when I explicitly specify to include Git ignored files, I still don't see them in my build artifact. I'm new to Poetry and this is pretty annoying.

Comment: @PsychoPunch hard to say what might be wrong without seeing your project structure. Just to be sure, absolute paths and starting with a `..` won't work, the source files need to be reachable relative to the pyproject.toml file.

Comment: @Arne I tried it with a fresh project, but I got the same result. Would you be able to quickly create a demo where it works? It looks to me like the `include` property does not override the `exclude`...

Comment: @PsychoPunch [here](https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/8ae4f94e4d319d25051099771fb1006a). Is that what you had it mind? Note that I'm only overriding the _default_ excludes, not explicit ones.

Comment: @Ame Thank you very much! I think what's missing is the `*` after `src/dlls`. Without that, Poetry will continue ignoring the files.

Comment: whoops, thanks for finding and correcting that.

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly none of the above answers worked for me. I also had a deeper structure where I wanted files not to be present in the repository, but to be recursively included upon building/publishing. The following globbing pattern worked out for me:

**.gitignore**

```
my_folder/
```

**pyproject.toml**

```
[tool.poetry]
...
include = ["**/my_folder/**/*.py"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66437801/404604), for directories that have deeper structure, use `*/**` to recursively add contents from the Git ignored directory.

**pyproject.toml**

```
[tool.poetry]
# other configuration here
include = ["src/extra/*/**"]
```

Comment: I think you have it backwards. The code uses [Path.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob), which says that `**` means "this directory and all subdirectories, recursively," so to get all files, you'd want `"src/extra/**/*"`. You can try `len([x for x in Path('/path/to/project').glob('src/extra/*/**') if x.is_file()])`, which for me shows `0` files.

Comment: The correction suggested by @paulie4 made it worked for me. I have a directory with generated Python code that I don't want to commit to Git (`generated` was added to .gitignore), but still be packaged by poetry. `include = ["generated/**/*"]` did what I wanted.